# What is cache related to Remote Config in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I got the concept of *Remote Config* in Firebase but while invoking `fetch()` method on the instance `FirebaseRemoteConfig` like:

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(3600)
```

one has to pass *cache expiration time* as here it is `3600`. But my question is, why does one have to pass *cache expiration* in `fetch()` method?. What is the use of *cache expiration* in the `fetch()` method? and What this `throttle` terminology related to `fetch`?
I've gone through this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android#caching but I didn't get details about the role of *cache* in fetching data while working with **FirerbaseRemoteConfig**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `fetch` in your app, you ensure that new configuration values (if any) are retrieved. Retrieving the remote configuration from the server is a relatively expensive operation, so the API is optimize to limit how frequently the values are refreshed. Between these refreshes, the last known values (which may either be the ones you hard-coded, or the ones that were last retrieved from the server) are kept in an on-device cache.

There are two overloads for `fetch`, one with no parameters, and one with a parameter called `cacheExpirationSeconds`. The [documentation for the latter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#fetch(long)) says:

> If the data in the cache was fetched no longer than this many seconds ago, this method will return the cached data. If not, a fetch from the Remote Config Server will be attempted.

So this means that if the remote configuration was retrieved less than `cacheExpirationSeconds` ago, this call will continue to use the values it already has. If the values were retrieve more than `cacheExpirationSeconds` ago, this will fetch new values.

The [documentation for the parameterless overload of `fetch()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#fetch(long)) says:

> This method uses the default cache expiration of 12 hours.

So calling this version is equivalent of calling `fetch(12*60*60)`.

Comment: Did you mean that when some data is passed through Remote Config from the Firebase console is stored in the device cache and then by invoking `fetch()` it is called?